# Setting up receiving an email when a certain Twitter user uses a hashtag they haven't used before

Tags: twitter, zapier, ifttt

Note: I'm not a developer.

I've scouted online for this question, but haven't been able to find an answer. I'm looking up to set up the following:

1. Track certain Twitter Accounts.
2. Trigger an event (sending me an email), when one of these Twitter Accounts uses a certain hashtag for the first time.

It sounds simple, but I haven't found a solution that does this. How would I go about and setting up something like this myself?

Comment: This is not that simple. First of all you will have to track the users full timeline for which hashtags they have used already. After that you will have to check every new post if the hashtags inside fit your pattern; the already used hashtags. If your condition is false, the event have to be triggered.

Comment: Also `zappier` and `ifttt` do not look like common implementations. Maybe try to explain or give a link, so the SO users can get a better understand of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

This looks doable, but will take some setup. The cleanest way to set this up depends on the volume of the hashtag and the number of hashtags you'll be tracking. If it's a very common hashtag, you'll want to watch only the users you're interested in. If it's not, it'll be cheaper to watch all tweets with that hashtag.

Either way, the gist will be using [Storage by Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/storage/integrations)) to keep a record of whether or not an account has used a given hashtag. The rough setup is as follows:

1. Twitter: User Tweet (Trigger)
2. Code using [StoreClient](https://zapier.com/help/storeclient-python/) (Action)
3. Filter
4. Email

When a tweet comes in, you'll check if it's a new combination of user & hashtag. If it is, store that it happened and send the email. If it's not new (a matching key is already found in storage), it'll catch on the filter and the zap won't progress.

This flow is going to be dramatically easier using code instead of discreed `Storage` steps, so I strongly recommend contacting a developer or reading through [this tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/) and the above StoreClient docs to read/write a list.

Hopefully that sets you in the direction. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!